# How to send Email using Logic App?

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-logic-apps

In one of my project I want to send email using Logic Apps, for that I followed below link.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/templates/101-logic-app-sendgrid/

From the above link i created the Logic App in my Azure Subscription 
and make designer in my logic app like this below figure. but i don't know which values can i gave in their text boxes.

My designer will be like this below figures.
[image]
[image]

but i don't know how to send email from newly created logic app in my azure portal.

Please tell me how can i achieve this.

-Pradeep

Comment: Sorry did not understand what is the question, is it how to send the request to logic app so that "SendGrid" email will be sent or how to configure "send grid". For LogicApp if you save the logic app the http will have a url generated to which you can send a request using some tool like Postman.

Comment: I am able to send an email using "send grid" using logicapp so let me know if you need some help.

Comment: I am sending http request along with json data but I don't know how can I access those json fields in the from, to, subject and email body fields od send email .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the json body coming in http request using the 
**"@{triggerBody()['propertyname']}**"

**checkout this blog for the details**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-http-endpoint/

Answer (score -1):

May you can see the following blog for step by step guidance.

https://sps-cloud-architect.blogspot.com/2019/12/azure-logic-apps-send-email-using-send.html